# Android Compose TextField with underline on misspelled words

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, textfield, misspelling

How I can create a TextField where if any word is misspelled it will create underline under the word or highlight for the user to go back if needed and click on it and the keyboard should show the suggested words.

Something like writing in Word where it let you continue writing but with wiggly red line if misspelled to go back and fix it.

some thing like this:

[Windows example for wiggly red line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioMbY.png)

Normal TextField but it did not highlight the misspilled words.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `keyboardOptions` to your `Textfield` with disabled `autoCorrect`

```
keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
    keyboardType = KeyboardType.Email,
    autoCorrect = false
)
```

Comment: it did work, it didn't add any lines under the misspelled words

Comment: sorry I meant "it didn't work", it didn't add any lines under the misspelled words

Comment: did you try to set autoCorrect to true?

Comment: yes, I tried both, it will not highlight or add lines under the misspelled  words